# Why can't application can't been accessed which deploy by docker stack in a docker swarm cluster?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

In a docker swarm cluster, there is one master and two workers.

Make a yaml file on master host:

stack.yml

```
version: '3.1'

services:

  wordpress:
    image: wordpress
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: example

  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: example
```

### Deploy the stack by docker stack

```
$ docker stack deploy -c stack.yml wordpress
```

Check on master host:

```
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
f24d160ef788        wordpress:latest    "docker-entrypoint.s…"   19 seconds ago      Up 13 seconds       80/tcp              wordpress_wordpress.1.5rilktpp43xtv1avtmp0uuh0u

# This is I downloaded the images myself:
$ docker images
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
wordpress           latest              c649c99a766e        12 hours ago        408MB
mysql               5.7                 0d16d0a97dd1        2 weeks ago         372MB

$ docker service ls
ID                  NAME                  MODE                REPLICAS            IMAGE               PORTS
ra3wfcq8owmb        wordpress_mysql       replicated          1/1                 mysql:5.7
hosko1vl55wq        wordpress_wordpress   replicated          1/1                 wordpress:latest    *:8080->80/tcp
```

Check on worker1 host:

```
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
f91c127d6166        wordpress:latest    "docker-entrypoint.s…"   12 seconds ago      Up 10 seconds       80/tcp              wordpress_wordpress.1.98fkpvprkdjwkdik2hieqcg7g

$ docker images
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
wordpress           <none>              c649c99a766e        12 hours ago        408MB
```

Check on worker2 host:

```
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED              STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
6465e16ee5b4        0d16d0a97dd1        "docker-entrypoint.s…"   About a minute ago   Up About a minute   3306/tcp            wordpress_mysql.1.xhrfekxylgycyp0qf6ca7h9ok

$ docker images
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
wordpress           <none>              c649c99a766e        12 hours ago        408MB
```

Can't access from http://[IP]:8080.

### Deploy it by docker-compose

```
$ docker-compose -f stack.yml up
```

Works very well.

---

## Questions

- Why deployed by `docker stack ...` didn't pull the images on all the cluster hosts?
- Why it can't been accessed but `docker-compose` way can?
- Is `docker-compose` way also deploy the containers on the whole swarm cluster?

---

## See service logs

(Changed IP)

```
$ docker service logs -f wordpress_wordpress
wordpress_wordpress.1.yiowxbsrup5v@ip-1-2-3-4.ap-northeast-1.compute.internal    |
wordpress_wordpress.1.yiowxbsrup5v@ip-1-2-3-4.ap-northeast-1.compute.internal    | Warning: mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/2002): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in Standard input code on line 22
wordpress_wordpress.1.yiowxbsrup5v@ip-1-2-3-4.ap-northeast-1.compute.internal    |
wordpress_wordpress.1.yiowxbsrup5v@ip-1-2-3-4.ap-northeast-1.compute.internal    | MySQL Connection Error: (2002) php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known
wordpress_wordpress.1.yiowxbsrup5v@ip-1-2-3-4.ap-northeast-1.compute.internal    |
wordpress_wordpress.1.yiowxbsrup5v@ip-1-2-3-4.ap-northeast-1.compute.internal    | Warning: mysqli::__construct(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in Standard input code on line 22
wordpress_wordpress.1.yiowxbsrup5v@ip-1-2-3-4.ap-northeast-1.compute.internal    |
wordpress_wordpress.1.yiowxbsrup5v@ip-1-2-3-4.ap-northeast-1.compute.internal    | Warning: mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/2002): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in Standard input code on line 22
wordpress_wordpress.1.yiowxbsrup5v@ip-1-2-3-4.ap-northeast-1.compute.internal    |
wordpress_wordpress.1.yiowxbsrup5v@ip-1-2-3-4.ap-northeast-1.compute.internal    | MySQL Connection Error: (2002) php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known
wordpress_wordpress.1.ei7e4zio6rj1@ip-1-2-3-5.ap-northeast-1.compute.internal    | WordPress not found in /var/www/html - copying now...
wordpress_wordpress.1.ei7e4zio6rj1@ip-1-2-3-5.ap-northeast-1.compute.internal    | Complete! WordPress has been successfully copied to /var/www/html
wordpress_wordpress.1.ei7e4zio6rj1@ip-1-2-3-5.ap-northeast-1.compute.internal    |
wordpress_wordpress.1.ei7e4zio6rj1@ip-1-2-3-5.ap-northeast-1.compute.internal    | Warning: mysqli::__construct(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in Standard input code on line 22
wordpress_wordpress.1.ei7e4zio6rj1@ip-1-2-3-5.ap-northeast-1.compute.internal    |
wordpress_wordpress.1.ei7e4zio6rj1@ip-1-2-3-5.ap-northeast-1.compute.internal    | MySQL Connection Error: (2002) php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known
wordpress_wordpress.1.ei7e4zio6rj1@ip-1-2-3-5.ap-northeast-1.compute.internal    |
wordpress_wordpress.1.ei7e4zio6rj1@ip-1-2-3-5.ap-northeast-1.compute.internal    | Warning: mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/2002): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in Standard input code on line 22
wordpress_wordpress.1.ei7e4zio6rj1@ip-1-2-3-5.ap-northeast-1.compute.internal    |
wordpress_wordpress.1.ei7e4zio6rj1@ip-1-2-3-5.ap-northeast-1.compute.internal    | Warning: mysqli::__construct(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in Standard input code on line 22
wordpress_wordpress.1.ei7e4zio6rj1@ip-1-2-3-5.ap-northeast-1.compute.internal    |
wordpress_wordpress.1.ei7e4zio6rj1@ip-1-2-3-5.ap-northeast-1.compute.internal    | Warning: mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/2002): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in Standard input code on line 22
wordpress_wordpress.1.ei7e4zio6rj1@ip-1-2-3-5.ap-northeast-1.compute.internal    |
wordpress_wordpress.1.ei7e4zio6rj1@ip-1-2-3-5.ap-northeast-1.compute.internal    | MySQL Connection Error: (2002) php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known
wordpress_wordpress.1.ei7e4zio6rj1@ip-1-2-3-5.ap-northeast-1.compute.internal    |
wordpress_wordpress.1.ei7e4zio6rj1@ip-1-2-3-5.ap-northeast-1.compute.internal    | Warning: mysqli::__construct(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in Standard input code on line 22
wordpress_wordpress.1.ei7e4zio6rj1@ip-1-2-3-5.ap-northeast-1.compute.internal    |
wordpress_wordpress.1.ei7e4zio6rj1@ip-1-2-3-5.ap-northeast-1.compute.internal    | Warning: mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/2002): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in Standard input code on line 22
wordpress_wordpress.1.ei7e4zio6rj1@ip-1-2-3-5.ap-northeast-1.compute.internal    |
wordpress_wordpress.1.ei7e4zio6rj1@ip-1-2-3-5.ap-northeast-1.compute.internal    | MySQL Connection Error: (2002) php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known
wordpress_wordpress.1.ei7e4zio6rj1@ip-1-2-3-5.ap-northeast-1.compute.internal    |
wordpress_wordpress.1.ei7e4zio6rj1@ip-1-2-3-5.ap-northeast-1.compute.internal    | Warning: mysqli::__construct(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in Standard input code on line 22
wordpress_wordpress.1.ei7e4zio6rj1@ip-1-2-3-5.ap-northeast-1.compute.internal    |
wordpress_wordpress.1.ei7e4zio6rj1@ip-1-2-3-5.ap-northeast-1.compute.internal    | Warning: mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/2002): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in Standard input code on line 22
wordpress_wordpress.1.ei7e4zio6rj1@ip-1-2-3-5.ap-northeast-1.compute.internal    |
wordpress_wordpress.1.ei7e4zio6rj1@ip-1-2-3-5.ap-northeast-1.compute.internal    | MySQL Connection Error: (2002) php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known
```

Can't connect to mysql.

Comment: Sorry, I have trouble understanding your English. May you correct your "_can't can't_" and "_can't been_"?

Comment: please check logs with `docker service logs -f wordpress_wordpress` and copy/paste them somewhere I can see them. It is strange that you have instances of this service on two hosts (manager and worker1) but scaling is set to 1 (the default)

Comment: @ConstantinGalbenu I added the result of that command to the question. It can be run only on swarm manager.

Comment: Add the following environment variable to the wordpress service:  WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: mysql:3306